# How to use varaibles in apex soql query

Tags: apex, invocablevariable

I have a set of invocable variables in my below apex code and I'm hoping to replace the "Workflow_Step_Lookup__c" field that's in the SOQL statement with the "lookUpField" variable. When I try using ":lookUpField" I get an error saying the expression cannot be assigned.

Is it possible to use apex variables in this scenario? If so Would anyone be able to assist me with how? The apex executes without error as is and I'm able to use the "templateID" variable in the SOQL but I'm not sure why I can't use the other variable.

Thanks in advance

```
global class SendWithDS2 implements queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
 global class EnvelopeSendResponse{
    global String message {get; private set;}
    global Boolean status {get; private set;}
    
    global EnvelopeSendResponse(final String message, final Boolean status){
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
    }
 }
InvocableVariables[] request;
public SendWithDS2(InvocableVariables[] request) {
    this.request = request;
}
@InvocableMethod    
public static void sendEnvelopeMethod(List <InvocableVariables> request){
    System.enqueueJob(new SendWithDS2(request));
}
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    //invocable variables
    Id mySourceId = request[0].mySourceId;
    Id templateId = request[0].templateId;
    String lookUpField = request[0].lookUpField;
    
    //response variable
    EnvelopeSendResponse response;
    
    try {
        
        //Get template UUID using SF ID
        dfsle__EnvelopeConfiguration__c DocuSignEnvelope = [SELECT dfsle__DocuSignId__c FROM dfsle__EnvelopeConfiguration__c WHERE ID =: templateId];
        
        //Create a list of recipients from the Relationship Link junction object
        List<contact>  LstContacts= [Select Id, Name, Email from Contact where Id in (Select Contact__c from Relationship_Link__c where Workflow_Step_Lookup__c =: mySourceId)];
        
        // Create an empty envelope
        dfsle.Envelope myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.getEmptyEnvelope
            (new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId));
        List<dfsle.Recipient> lstRecipient=new List<dfsle.Recipient>();
       
        // Setup recipient data
        for(Contact myCustomer : LstContacts)
        {
            system.debug('myCustomer.Email' + myCustomer.Email);
            dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource
                (myCustomer.Name, myCustomer.Email, null, 'Signer 1', new dfsle.Entity(mySourceId));
            lstRecipient.add(myRecipient);
        }
        
        // Add Recipients to the Envelope
        myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withRecipients(lstRecipient);
        
        // myTemplateId contains the DocuSign Id of the DocuSign Template
        dfsle.UUID myTemplateId = dfsle.UUID.parse(DocuSignEnvelope.dfsle__DocuSignId__c);
        
        // Create a new document for the Envelope
        dfsle.Document myDocument = dfsle.Document.fromTemplate(
            myTemplateId, // templateId in dfsle.UUID format
            'Contact Template'); // The name of the template
        List<dfsle.Document> workFlowDocs=dfsle.DocumentService.getLinkedDocuments(ContentVersion.getSObjectType(),new Set<ID>{ mySourceId },false);
        workFlowDocs.add(myDocument);
        
        // Add document to the Envelope
        //myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withDocuments(new List<dfsle.Document> { myDocument });
        myEnvelope = myEnvelope.withDocuments(workFlowDocs);
        
        // Send the envelope
        myEnvelope = dfsle.EnvelopeService.sendEnvelope(
            myEnvelope, // The envelope to send
            true); // Send now?
        
        // Retrieve the five most recent envelope statuses from the Salesforce source object.
        // The status results are sorted oldest to newest.
        List<dfsle.Envelope.Status> myStatus = dfsle.StatusService.getStatus(
            new Set<Id> { // IDs of the Salesforce objects with associated status.
                mySourceId
                    },
            5); // Maximum number of records to return.
        
        response = new EnvelopeSendResponse('Envelope sent successfully', true);
        system.debug('response' + response);
        
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        response = new EnvelopeSendResponse(ex.getMessage(), false);
    }
    
}        
global class InvocableVariables{
    // The ID of the initiating Salesforce object, recipient and template
    @InvocableVariable public Id mySourceId;
    @InvocableVariable public Id templateId;
    @InvocableVariable public String lookUpField;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the `Workflow_Step_Lookup__c` field is present on the object, it is part of the metadata(which is fixed).

The `templateID` variable refers to the row data in the object, so you can access it as a variable.

If the statement, `String lookUpField = request[0].lookUpField;` always evaluates to a field present on the object, you can use [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)

So the query string can be something like,

```
String mySourceId = 'sourceId';
List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('Select Id, Name, Email from Contact where Id in (Select Contact__c from Relationship_Link__c where '+lookUpField+' =: mySourceId');
```

See if this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much this worked!